# cakephp: remove html tag from title markup in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I am new to bootstrap, I am using title markup and  assigned data to title from database(in which data contain html tag) but facing issue, it is displaying data along with html tag  when hover on associated text.

```
<div title="<?php echo $abc['Abc']['description']; ?>">
      <?php echo $abc['Abc']['name']; ?>
</div>
```

output generated by title when hover on text :

```
<p> description of abc name</p>
```

How can i remove html tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, `strip_tags()` can be used to remove HTML tags.

Replace:

```
<?php echo $abc['Abc']['description']; ?>
```

with:

```
<?php echo strip_tags($abc['Abc']['description']); ?>
```

Reference: [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: People always forget the h(): `h($abc['Abc']['description'])` or `h(strip_tags(...))` Just by stripping the tags it doesnt mean there aren't any chars that could potentially harm the HTML around it. So always escape your non HTML output.